# Schur's Triangularization Lemma in Hefferon's Linear Algebra textbook

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reviewing some material and came to this:

> Fix a basis $B = \{\vec{\beta}_1, \ldots, \vec{\beta}_n\}$ for $V$ ($V$ is a vector space) and observe that the spans
>   $$
> [\emptyset] = \{\vec{0}\} \subset [\{\vec{\beta}_1\}] \subset [\{\vec{\beta}_1, \vec{\beta}_2\}] \subset \cdots \subset [B] = V
> $$
>   form a stricly increasing chain of subspaces ($[]$ means "the span of"). Show that for any linear map $h: V \to W$ there is a chain $W_0 = \{\vec{0}\} \subseteq W_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq W_m = W$ of subspaces of W such that
>   $$
> h([\{\vec{\beta}_1, \ldots, \vec{\beta}_i\}]) \subset W_i
> $$
>   for each $i$.

The answer sheet says to take $W_i$ to be the span of $\{h(\vec{\beta}_1),\ldots,h(\vec{\beta}_i)\}$.

Now, my question is, how is it true that $h([\{\vec{\beta}_1, \ldots, \vec{\beta}_i\}]) \subset [\{h(\vec{\beta}_1),\ldots,h(\vec{\beta}_i)\}]$? Are these two not identical since $h$ is a linear map?

The book can be found [here](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf) (pg. 212) and the answers [here](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/jhanswer.pdf) (pg. 180).

Comment: In my humble opinion you are perfectly right, and we have $h(span(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_i)) = span(h(\beta_1),\ldots,h(\beta_i)) =: W_i.$ Another strange thing is that if we take this defition of $W_i,$ then we don't necessarily have $W_m = W,$ as claimed by the exercise. Or is $h$ assumed to be onto? I don't see that.

Comment: @jflipp: Thanks. Regarding your remark, shouldn't $h$ be _one-to-one_ (not _onto_) in order for $\{h(\vec{\beta}_1), \ldots, h(\vec{\beta}_n)\}$ to be a basis for $W$ (that would also imply that $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$) whenever $\{\vec{\beta}_1, \ldots, \vec{\beta}_n\}$ is a basis for $V$?

Comment: I just realized that if $h$ is one-to-one, then $\{h(\vec{\beta}_1), \ldots, h(\vec{\beta}_n)\}$ is a basis for only the range space of $h$ (denoted as $\mathscr{R}(h)$ in the book), not for all of $W$. It would have to be an isomorphism for it to be a basis for all of $W$. I hope I didn't overlook something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the $\subset$ to a $\subseteq$.  Thank you for the report (OP emailed me separately).

(If you are a person led here by Googling something about the book, and you have a bug report, can I ask you please to send it to the contact address listed on [the book's download page](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra) since I am not a regular reader of this site.  Thanks. --Jim)